# Compile error while returning string arrays

Tags: java, android

```
public String[] get_file_names_from_SD() /* Compiler complains here */ 
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/journal_storage");
        if (dir.exists() & dir.isDirectory()) {
            return (dir.list());            
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Media Mounted Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

So I am returning `dir.list()` which will contain an array of strings but for some reason compiler is showing an error "This method must return a result of type String[]".

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28%29), the method returns an array of Strings.

Can anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: instead of `&`, there should be `&&` in condition.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code paths of your method are **NOT** returning the `String[]`. You should return the `String[]` or `null` in the `else` block also since else block is a reachable code block of your method.

```
public String[] get_file_names_from_SD() /*Compiler complains here*/
    {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/journal_storage");
            if(dir.exists() & dir.isDirectory())
            {
                return(dir.list());

            }

        }
        else
        {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Media Mounted Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //--> return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puıt this line after your else statement:

```
return null;
```

This will guarantee that your method will return successfully. However, you should watch for `NullPointerException`s where you invoke this method.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the call paths lead to returning a String[], for e.g. if your SD card is not MOUNTED the control goes to the else block and doesn't return anything. You can simply end it with a `return null;` statement at the end of the block to make that error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your else block is not returning anything .. Thats Y the error is thrown

```
else
    {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Media Mounted Issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // return something here .. If nothing , return null
    }
```